# WebRTC Video Renderer

Tags: c++, winapi, webrtc

We're busy trying to render the frames we get from WebRTC, but we are having problems showing the video correctly.

Does anyone have experience in this or is there an guide online that shows how to render frames from WebRTC in win32?

We are building out application in Visual Studio 2013. We used OpenGL for an previous attempt and we use Direct3D now, a guide with either is fine for us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the problem exactly? It's just a block of I420 format pixel data.

With any YUV -> RGB conversion method(even WebRTC library provide one), remain work to do is just drawing RGB bitmap to a window.

In my personal experience, conversion was really fast, and drawing to the buffer(memory DC, backbuffer) was sufficiently fast. Only issue was actual screen presentation. For this, Direct2D was most convenient.

Comment: The problem is not the rendering, it's the actual conversion. We tried using convertToRgbBuffer(), but the data that ends up in the buffer is garbage.

Comment: I know this is coming a bit late, but you could use OpenCV to do the conversion. It provides a method for converting images between colourspaces and a bunch of other stuff for manipulating images, which could be useful depending on what you're planning on doing with it. The method you want is

`cv::cvtColor(inputImage, outputImage, CV_YUV420p2RGB, 0);`